# Docker swarm load balancing

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Do we need to balance load via ngnix with swarm mode?

If so, why do we need to do that. Docker swarm balances load. I tested for simple application. It has several strategies for load balancing.

Even docker swarm balances load, why are there so many articles about load balancing with ngnix in swarm mode?

Answer (score 6):

> Do we need to balance load via ngnix with swarm mode?

Yes and no. It depends ... :)
Application load balancing is doing the swarm for you. E.g. when deploying a service with a replica of 10, the swarm mode will perform a round robin load balancing around your 10 applications everytime you call it. It doen't matter which manager or worker you're calling.

But on host level, you need an external classic load balancer. E.g. when your swarm runs on 4 digital ocean machines, you need a load balancer which covers all 4 ip adresses.

> Even docker swarm balances load, why are there so many articles about load balancing with ngnix in swarm mode?

a) Because nginx wants to earn money
b) Because there was a time before docker swarm mode exists and where everything was complicated
c) Because it's still good to know how to do it yourself
d) Because you're very familar with nginx

Comment: Another difference between docker swarm load balancing and some other load balancing solutions can be their layer in network. Docker swarm uses L4 load balancing while NGINX and HA proxy use layer7. useful article here https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-using-Docker-Swarm-and-HAProxy   I think if we need just load balancing between nodes, swarm works well, otherwise if we need more intelligent load balancing according to HTTP headers it's better using a L7 load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

The new feature in `Docker 1.12` make `Swarm` a powerful platform, but this will be enhanced by taking advantage of open source `NGINX` and even more by using `NGINX Plus`. The ability of `NGINX Plus` to dynamically reconfigure the back-end containers to load balance using `DNS`, and the visibility provided by the `Status API`, make for a very powerful container solution.

There is this article which is very descriptive in explaining why is this so advantageous. Link [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/docker-swarm-load-balancing-nginx-plus/).

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Does this answer your question @GopsAB?